# Left Subset Duplicates INDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have reading a document which about duplicate index. In the example it showed Left subset duplicate index and what it is suggesting is that if I have index like the following I should consider removing TransRefId field from the index since Sql server will always use the first index.

Can someone explain me the logic behind that?

Index1  [DATAAREAID],[ITEMID],[DATESTATUS]

Index2  [DATAAREAID],[ITEMID],[DATESTATUS],[TRANSREFID]*

Comment: `Sql server will always use the first index`... Uh, I don't believe this statement is true. But regardless, what indexes you should use depend on what queries you're running on a table.

Comment: So I have define the index 2 first then SQL server would have used the index 2. is that correct understanding.

Comment: I'm not extremely knowledgeable in this area, but I believe if SQL has the option of two indexes that would perform the same, there's no _real_ rhyme or reason to which one it chooses. Some discussion on this can be found [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21183/how-does-the-database-decide-which-index-to-use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the opposite. That is, given the two indexes you have defined, all queries that can be satisfied by the first can be satisfied by the second, but the opposite is not true. That is, if you have a where clause with predicates on all of [DATAAREAID],[ITEMID],[DATESTATUS], and [TRANSREFID], then the first index will take [TRANSFERID] as a residual predicate (i.e. one that can't be seeked to) and will have to evaluate all rows that match on the first three to see if the fourth matches.

Now, that said, there may be cases where it makes sense to have both indexes! Consider the case where your normal OLTP workload is well-served by having the second index, but it's a wide index. You also have an infrequently running but time critical process that would be able to use the first index which, absent the fourth column, is narrow. Indexing is somewhat of an art.